# Why do interlaced jpegs are bigger than non-interlaced image?

Tags: jpeg, interlacing

To gain on speed, in an application, I've tried to fill each horizontal odd line of pixels with the pixels from the previous even horizontal line. The problem is that I thought I'd save a bit on space, but for 20% of speed gain, the size of my stack of jpegs has almost doubled.

I'm now thinking about just skipping the image processing on odd line, instead of copying the previous pixels on odd line, since there's no gain on file size.

Am I preventing the jpeg codec from compressing the image when I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform), which is used in JPEG compression algorithm won't be too effective on sharp details you are artificially creating.

If you want to save on space reducing vertical resolution, don't just copy lines, scale it down be 2 on vertical axis and scale up by 2 when displaying.

But it WILL look ugly.

Comment: Can't say anything without seeing images themselves. It's too content-dependent.

Comment: 640x480 camera capture video from anything.

Comment: What is time/scene difference between adjacent images? Maybe video compression will be more suitable for your task, if they have much in common?

Comment: I'm on WindowsPhone, and the encoder is not accessible from any API. That's why my videos are m-jpeg. I don't have the knowledge to port any simple h.264 or Mpeg with prediction c++ project to C#.

Comment: Hum you just raised a very good point about time/scene difference. At 10-15 fps, the time delta can go up to 100ms between images. So even P-Frames is not the Moon.

Comment: Oh. Then you are into trouble. MJPEG is always huge. The only way to reduce bandwidth is to sacrifice spatial or temporal resolution.

Comment: I'm cutting my 640x480 screen to ""360p"" to gain speed on some fx. But yeah, I'll to make some researches to code a better codec.